# How to implement single DeleteMapping for 2 parameters?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a user table in my database with 2 fields **id** and **name**. I want to create an API to delete a user on the bases of id or name. Like this:

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> clearUser(@PathVariable("name") String name){
        myService.deleteUser(name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> clearUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        myService.deleteUser(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But I want to do it under one `@DeleteMapping` and I have to do it using path param only not query param. A person can enter id or name to delete that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use your two path variables as optional.

```
@DeleteMapping(path = {"/{name}", "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> clearUser(@PathVariable("name") Optional<String> name, @PathVariable("id") Optional<Integer> id){
    myService.deleteByIdOrName(id, name);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

  MyRepo ...
  void deleteByIdOrName(Optional<Integer> id, Optional<String> name);

  MyService
  void deleteByIdOrName(Optional<Integer> id, Optional<String> name) {
      repo.deleteByIdOrName(id, name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the path parameter type whether it is numeric or a String. Based on that, you can change the implementation under one method. just a hint:

```
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{user}") 
public ResponseEntity clearUser(@PathVariable("user") String user){ 
       myService.deleteUser(user);    
       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and inside the implementation, do the following:

use Java's built-in java.text.NumberFormat object to see if, after 
  parsing the string the parser position is at the end of the string. If 
  it is, we can assume the entire string is numeric:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) { 
       NumberFormat formatter = 
       NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
       ParsePosition pos = new 
       ParsePosition(0); 
       formatter.parse(str, pos); 
       return str.length() == pos.getIndex(); 
    }
    ....

    if(isNumeric(user)){
       // implement delete by ID
    }else{
       //implement delete by Name
    }

....
```

Hope this will give you an idea..

Comment: What happens in the worst case if the user have a name 123. This is not a good solution.